# using zend framework components without framework and getting typehints in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework

Using eclipse juno, I would like to use some of ZF components in my project without the framework.

I thought I can use them with require_once statements, without the class autoloader. I put the ZF sources in include path. But eclipse is not typehinting ZF classes if I use require_once to import classes. However if I use the "use" statement eclipse is typehinting.

I expect to typehint after I write "require_once 'Zend/ ..." this is not happening. But if I type "use Zend " it is typehinting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I moved to zend framework sources into eclipse workspace and it worked. Do not know why it did not worked outside. ZF is an external library and should be on outside of workspace. anyway my problem is solved. I use two copies of ZF one for typehinting.

Comment: Eclipse maintains its own "Include Path", i.e. it does not parse the PHP include path. Right click on your project and add the path to your library or sources.

Comment: this happened even if I added the include path. after that I moved the library into workspace and make it a project and put that project in includes list and it worked. Anyway I don't know the reason. I can work like this.